# i want to remove data from gridview after data is stored in other table

Tags: .net

i want to remove data from gridview after data is stored in other table.. By my code only first row data is remove from gridview other is avilable ...
my code is that:-

```
 void gridshw2()
    {
        cn.Open();
        s = "Select * from persn_info";
        try
        {
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(s, cn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "set");
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView2.DataMember = "set";

            s = "select sub_no from paymnt_info";
            cm = new OleDbCommand(s, cn);
            rd = cm.ExecuteReader();
            if (rd.Read())
            {

                    if (rd["sub_no"].ToString() == dataGridView2.Rows[].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                    {
                        dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
                    }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ea)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ea.Message);
        }
        finally {
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be enough:

```
 dataGridView2.DataSource=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

in table take one status column if your record  has been gone from one grid view to other then update table first grid view by method and then call in on that button those apply for second grid view and call also in form load